# how store a value to use anywhere in MVC throughout a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

Hey guys need help here

i want to store few Values in my MVC Project through out the session such as UserId,EmailId,RoleId and others.

right now i am creating session variable for this purpose and storing all those values in session variable,is there any other way to store a value throughout the session as i have read using session variable is not safe, and viewdata,tempdata,viewbag store data temporarily

Comment: Why it is not safe? Is it applied to your application/configuration?

Comment: I don't think that your question fits `SO` demands for "good" question. It's too broad and opinion based. You better focus your question on "How to do it" rather than "What to do". But back to your question - you need to read about security management in `ASP.NET` there are indeed a lot of ways to keep sensitive data like reading from the database or what I think is most popular now - using identity token. But yet again for now you are asking a little bit too much so I don't think anyone can give you exact answer.

Comment: Encrypt the data in the session

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom object and store this in the HttpContext.

In the global.asax, hook the OnSessionStart event

```
void OnSessionStart(...)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("__CustomUserData", new UserDataObject());
}
```

From anywhere in code where the HttpContext.Current property != null you can retrive that object. Created an extension in my projects

```
public static UserDataObject GetCustomUserDataObject(this HttpContext current)
{
    return current != null ? (UserDataObject)current.Session["__CustomUserData"] : null;
}
```

In your controller or manager you can access it following way then:

```
var userData = HttpContext.Current.GetCustomUserDataObject();
```

REMARK:

However, for default userId and userName I would suggest to use the Mvc Identity System (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Comment: 1. `How should we set the value initially - so that we are able to get it from GetCustomUserDataObject?`
2. `Should the session[__CustomUserData"] be initailly set? `
3. `If so its still using session right?`

Comment: As My requirement is to retain the selected `Client` and `Device` and to have their values throughout the web app - as all the data processed in different pages  will be tightly related to the selected Client & Device